# Embedding torus in space such that its 6-fold symmetry extends

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

The following question is Problem 1.1.2.c in Thurston's book "Three-dimensional geometry and topology".  I have not managed to solve it despite quite a bit of effort.

One can obtain a 2-dimensional torus $T$ by identifying the sides of a hexagon in an appropriate way (see, for example, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling)).  By rotating this hexagon, we can obtain an order $6$ self-map of $T$.  The question is whether we can embed $T$ into either $\mathbb{R}^3$ or $S^3$ such that this self-map extends to an order $6$ self-map of the ambient space.  My guess is that the answer is "no", at least for $\mathbb{R}^3$.  I'm less sure about $S^3$.

Thanks!

Comment: If the torus embeds equivariantly, the corresponding torus bundle over $S^1$ smoothly embeds in $S^4$ and you can use various obstructions from 4-manifold theory to rule out embedding.  The torus bundle over $S^1$ is a Seifert fibred space.  Do you know it's "name" in un-normalized Seifert notation?  That would help. 

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  How do you get a torus bundle over $S^1$ from an order $6$ homeomorphism of $S^3$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ that preserves a torus?

Comment: Oh, here's a far simpler strategy.  If the torus embeds, it bounds a solid torus on one side.  What automorphisms are their of order $6$ for a solid torus?  

Comment: The torus bundle is $(S^1 \times S^1) \times [0,1]$ modulo the equivalence relation $(p,0) \sim (f(p),1)$ where $f : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ is your order six automorphism. 

Comment: IMO the "simpler strategy" is the way to go!

Comment: It seems pretty hard to classify order 6 homeomorphisms of a solid torus.  Indeed, this seems even harder than classifying involutions of $S^3$, which is a pretty wild problem (for example, you have the wild involution Bing constructed out of the solid Alexander horned sphere).

Comment:  You don't need a classification result for this problem.  Hint: An automorphism of a solid torus has to preserve the meridional class of the torus (up to sign) -- the non-trivial cycle that bounds a disc in the solid torus. 

Comment: Wow, I'm a little embarrassed that I did not see that.  Thanks Ryan!

Comment: What is the smallest $n$ such that you can embed it in $\mathbb R^n$ with that symmetry? 4?

Comment: Further discussion should take place on Meta: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1294/questions-from-graduatelevel-books-asked-by-new-users/#Item_0

Please upvote this comment so it appears "above the fold"

Comment: This comment thread got a bit out of hand with "meta conversation." This kind of conversation is a good thing, but I think it's worth keeping MO itself on topic. So I deleted several of the meta comments. However, the full comment thread has been copied to meta.MO: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1294/questions-from-graduatelevel-books-asked-by-new-users/#Comment_18202

Comment: I strongly recommend that the post either be edited or removed.  I give my view of why on the meta.mathoverflow thread mentioned above. Gerhard Paseman, 2012.01.29

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lurking here on MO, I've noticed that unanswered questions get bumped to the top periodically.  Since this question was answered by Ryan Budney in the comments, I've decided to write his answer here (marked "community wiki" so I get no reputation points) to prevent this from happening.

The answer is no for both $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $S^3$.  I'll give the details for $\mathbb{R}^3$; the other case is similar.  Fix an embedding $T^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$.  The first step is to show that $T^2$ is the boundary of a closed regular neighborhood $N$ of a knot.  This is a nontrivial fact; for an exposition, see for example [this](http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~gadgil/expos/Tori.pdf).  The space $N$ is a solid torus, and thus up to homotopy there exists exactly one simple closed curve $\gamma$ in $T^2$ which bounds a disc in $N$.  Any homeomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ which preserves $T^2$ must take $\gamma$ to a curve on $T^2$ homotopic to $\gamma$.  In other words, the restriction of $\phi$ to $T^2$ must fix a nonzero vector in $H_1(T^2;\mathbb{Z})$.  But the automorphism in the question fixes no such vector.

Comment: You don't need to know that $N$ is a solid torus.  It is enough to know that $N$ is a compact manifold with $T = \partial N$.  Then by "one-half lives, one-half dies" (see Lemma 3.5 of Hatcher's 3-manifold notes) there is a unique cyclic subgroup $Z$ of $H_1(T)$ killed by the inclusion map of $T$ into $N$.  So the homeomorphism fixes the subgroup $Z$ and thus has an eigenvalue of $\pm 1$, a contradiction. 